# Using Reactjs Table row not being deleted when remove button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with inputs to track expenses. on form submit a table row is created with the data along with a delete button. On click of the remove button, the table row should remove itself from the table. I have the button being recognized in the console returning "clicked" and state is reset after the remove button is clicked but the row is not being deleted.

my handleDelete method inside my App component:

```
   handleDelete(i) {
     let expenseRows = [...this.state.expenses]
         expenseRows.splice(i,1) 
         this.setState({
            expenseRows: expenseRows
          })
        }

   <ExpenseTable handleDelete={this.handleDelete} expenses={this.state.expenses} />
```

Inside my ExpenseTable component:

```
   <tbody>
      {expenses.map((expense, i) => {
                return(
                       <tr key={expense.id} >
                         <td> {expense.payType} </td>
                         <td> {expense.itemPurchased} </td>
                         <td> {expense.payLocation} </td>
                         <td> ${expense.amountSpent} </td>
                         <td> {expense.dateOfPurchase} </td>
                         <td><button onClick={i => this.props.handleDelete(i)} >Remove</button></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake.

Change:

```
this.setState({
  expenseRows: expenseRows
});
```

To:

```
this.setState({
  expenses: expenseRows
});
```